# /etc/sudoer:1:5: syntax error

Tags: ros, syntax

Super new at linux, and I want to program robots.

I'm trying to work with ROS 2 in Ubuntu 22.04. I installed Ubuntu into a virtualbox with the iso. The very first thing I did without any changes was to open a terminal and start filling in commands from https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html

Every time I put in a command I get this output:

```
/etc/sudoers:1:5: syntax error
exit
^
```

Then sometimes the command runs but not this one:

```
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You have made an error in the file '/etc/sudoers'. 

Please update the question with the content of that file.

Comment: There are multiple methods listed in that link. Please list the actual commands you were using in _this post_.